# Trouble using the 7555 timer IC

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, flipflop, 555

I'm trying to build a circuit that uses T-flip-flops to generate the sequence "CSE231-1-6" on a 7-segment display. It works fine on logisim, so there are no design-related errors here.

So theoretically it's supposed to cycle between the 10 distinct states. However on the actual implementation, the display just cycles between 2 states infinitely- "C" and "S". I tried randomly swapping the flip-flop outputs to the input of the 4x16 decoder I used, and it still cycles between only 2 random states. For example: "S" and "2", "6" and "-" etc.

I'm guessing it has to do with the way I set up the [7555] timer IC. I followed the design of the IC in the picture attached (with different resistance and capacitance). It's a circuit for a metronome. Is that the problem? If not, where should I look for errors?

EDIT: I have uploaded the actual schematic of the 7555 connections, and the rest of the circuit.

[image]

And here's the rest of the circuit
[image]

Comment: Post the real circuit.  There's a schematic editor you can use if you edit your question.

Comment: Uploaded. Can you please check?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Problem solved! It was careless on my part. I forgot to check the data sheet for the 7473. So turns out, the **CLR inputs need to be logic-HIGH** in order for the flip-flops to work. This was my first time using the 7473 ICs, so I didn't know. But now it's working perfectly.

P.S- Sorry I couldn't upload the actual schematic. I was working on it and would have uploaded it for people to see. Maybe this would have been solved hours ago, had I done that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've mentioned a power supply in your previous questions.  The TTL logic ICs you've mentioned require a 5 volt power supply.  You should power the 7555 from the same supply, and connect the 7555's pin 3 directly to the clock inputs of the flip-flops.

You should also have 0.1 uF capacitors between the power and ground pins of all the ICs, as close as practical to each IC.

Comment: I've used a 5V power supply and powered the 555 with it as well. Pin-3 is directly connected to the clk inputs. I have a 10uF capacitor between ground and pins-2,6 of the 7555.

Comment: The 10 uF capacitor is part of the 7555's timing circuit.  You also need power supply bypass capacitors (0.1 uF) between the Vcc and Ground pins of each IC, as close to the IC as practical.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. But just out of curiosity, what exactly does that do to keep it from cycling between just 2 states?

Comment: The bypass capacitors will reduce noise on the power supply - the noise will be caused by the gates and flip-flops changing states, and may cause other parts to chage states when they shouldn't.  I don't guarantee they will fix the problem, but they are very strongly recommended in any digital circuit.  A full proper schematic of your circuit may help others diagnose problems.

Answer (score -1):

The 555 astable looks OK, basically, so you should post the schematic diagram of the circuit you're having trouble with, and how it's connected to the 555.

Comment: Uploaded. Can you please check?

Comment: We would like to see your real physical circuit, with the 7473s and other real parts, rather than your logisim simulator block diagram with fictional parts.

Comment: I used jumper-cables, so the circuit is a jungle of wires. I'm making a schematic using real IC pin configuration. But in the meantime,  I've done some testing and found that the 3rd flip-flop is generating 0 at its Q and 1 at it's Q' , without any change. J and K (shorted) are pulsating, and so is the clk, but there is no change in the output. I tried changing the IC, but that didn't help. I have simulated this in logisim, and indeed the display just cycles between 2 states- "C" and "S".What could cause this?